# Creating a basic C++ .dll for p/invoke in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am a C# programmer, and unfortunately due to both age and experience, I did not have the luxury of getting the chance to go through the C++ era of programming in my learning - so much of it is mysterious and new to me. Not really here to debate the importance of learning such or not, but I am in need of some help with what should be a trivial matter.

### PROBLEM

I need assistance in packaging my C++ code into a .dll. I do not have experience with C++ and am having a great deal of difficulty making a working .dll that I can p/invoke from (*Visual Studio 2010*). Please keep reading for more details and for the code I am trying to package.

### DETAILS

I have some code that needs to run in an unmanaged environment. Under normal circumstances, a simple p/invoke is suitable for this task. Wire up some `[ImportDll]` and you're good to go. Worst case scenario I can sometimes use Marshalling. However for reasons that I have yet to really discover, this does not seem possible with my present task.

I am trying to read some data from an `owner drawn list box` that was made in an old unmanaged C++ application, and get the text from it. I have seen several examples of how to do this - but they are in older VB6 code.

I have discovered the C++ equivalent, but this too is unsuitable for me. Even with p/invoke, there seems to be a lot of trouble with the moving of memory and how it needs to operate. The process is pretty simplistic.

> I need to create a simple C++ .dll that runs the method I need in unmanaged code, and populates a variable with the result.

As dumb as this sounds, **I do not know how to do this**. I have tried just running through the simple C++ Wizards in Visual Studio (using Visual Studio 2010) and I'm just not having luck. I was hoping someone could help me walk through this, and perhaps explain what is going on so I can learn from it.

Here is the code I need to place into a `.dll`.

The intention is for `hListWnd` to be passed as an `IntPtr` in C#, `index` will be a simple `Int32`, and `outputResult` will go to whatever is neccessary to make this work. In other p/invoke situations, I have seen this done with `System.Text.StringBuilder`, but I am willing to work with **anything** to make this work right.

```
void GetListItemData( HWND hListWnd, long index, char *outputResult )
{
    int result;
    DWORD processID;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    char *itemData;
    char sDataRead[5];
    DWORD bytes;
    DWORD lListItemHold, lListItemDataHold;
    *outputResult=0;

    if( hListWnd )
    {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId( hListWnd, &processID );

        hProcess=OpenProcess( 0x10|0xf0000|PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, processID );

        if( hProcess )
        {
            lListItemHold=(DWORD)SendMessage( hListWnd, LB_GETITEMDATA, index-1, 0 );
            lListItemHold=lListItemHold+24;

            result=ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, (void *)lListItemHold, &sDataRead, 4, &bytes );
            if( !result )
            {
                RaiseWinErr();
            }

            memcpy( &lListItemDataHold, &sDataRead, 4 );
            lListItemDataHold=lListItemDataHold+6;

            ReadProcessMemory( hProcess, (void *)lListItemDataHold, outputResult, 16, &bytes );

            CloseHandle( hProcess );
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can help me, please, I am begging here. This has become a very frustrating problem for me. I have tried to reproduce this in C# using `RtlMoveMemory` and `ReadProcessMemory` p/invoke, but to no avail. I have been hunting for days and days, and continue to come up with dead results. I know that some of the code does not make a lot of sense (I've had people ask me why it is requiring the `+6` and what the `+24` is, etc), and the absolute truth is that I don't **entirely** know. What I do know is that the **owner drawn list box** employs some graphics on it, and the purpose of these offsets is to examine the data beyond where the graphic area is drawn, because the actual structure of the `List Item` is unknown.

Another method I have tried is retrieving my item as an `IAccessible` using the `Accessibility.dll` library. This too proved fruitless. I have also tried `ManagedWinApi` from pinvoke.net and the libraries there did not prove any success.

I know this code works. It just doesn't work in C#. My theory is that using a `[DllImport]` to invoke it in C# will give me the desired result.

Thanks again for any help anyone provides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third parameter needs to be a byte[], marshalled as a char*, of size 16.

If you check the documentation for ReadProcessMemory, it takes a buffer and a size, and this function passes the size as 16 bytes. This means that you will need a 16-byte array. The runtime should be perfectly happy to marshal a byte[] of size 16. Be careful not to mix C++ char with C# char- the C# char is actually a C++ wchar_t on Windows. The C++ char is C#'s byte.

Not that I have any actual idea about how that functions works- I just traced the usage of the third parameter and it only actually gets passed to ReadProcessMemory, the parameters for which are quite clearly documented.

To package into a .dll (assuming you have nothing else to go into that .dll), you want to add a couple things on to the beginning to ask the C++ compiler not to mangle the name and to export it for you, producing this as the first line

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetListItemData( HWND hListWnd, long index, char *outputResult )
```

You'll only need one C++ source file, no headers, and compile as DLL (it's in the project settings). You won't need any code except the function and any includes that you need.

In C#

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(
    DLLPath,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl
)]
private static extern void GetListItemData(
    System.IntPtr hWnd,
    System.Int32 index,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]byte[] buffer
);
```

Unfortunately, it's up to you to make sure that buffer is of sufficient size.

Comment: Thank you ,but this isn't quite what I'm asking. I am asking for help packaging it into a _.dll_ - though debugging it is also very appreciated. If you know how this could could be written in C#, I would be very anxious to see it - but all of my attempts to translate it have failed.

Comment: Sorry- your question isn't very specific about what the actual current problem *is*.

Comment: So I want to just go through the Visual Studio Wizard, and not let it create anything, and just add a single .cpp file?

Comment: I apologize for so many questions, C++ is so foreign to me. You stated some problems with the code itself, could I bother you to post an addendum to your text and show me what you would fix? I'm trying to follow along and I am a little bit confused.

Comment: No, no. I'm not saying it's bad or broken, because I don't understand it much. It's much too WinAPI specific for me to analyze as good or bad- I don't use the native WinAPI very much. Yes- you want just one .cpp file. Include the Windows headers (don't see any other dependencies). Set the project in settings to compile to .DLL. Compile.

Comment: Wait, Windows headers? I'm not sure what you mean by that. How do I include those?

Comment: You type `#include <Windows.h>` at the top of the file.

Comment: So when you say a 16-byte array, will `byte[] rBytes = new byte[16];` suffice for that? So I could call it such as ... `RetrieveListItem(hWnd,i, rBytes);` ? Where `i` is the index, and `rBytes` is a `byte[16]`?

Comment: Okay, well, thanks to you I got the .dll made and I can indeed query it - though the data I am getting back is still wrong. I was certain that C# was the problem... I will be creating a new question for this actual C++ code, because I still have to fix the problem. Thank you for your help.