# Looking for code sample on creating C++ DLL then P/Invoke in C# (For Windows CE 5/6)

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am experienced in C# but not in C++. Recently my Windows CE 5 C# program is hitting performance issue and I am considering moving calculation to C++ DLL then P/Invoke it from C# since C++ supports hardware float-point co-processor while .NET CF does not.

I am searching the net all morning trying to find a complete sample that demonstrate creating C++ DLL then P/Invoke in C# but could not find any.

Could anyone point some good sample or article for me?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Are you serious that C# emulates floating point operations in software? I'm not familiar with C#, but I find that very surprising.

Comment: .NET CF certainly supports an FPU.  At least do some minimal tests to ensure you are actually ahead, it isn't very likely.  And write your DLL in C, you can't pinvoke a DLL with C++ classes.

Comment: C++ supports SIMD instructions, .NETCF does not.  I assume that's what wei means by "hardware floating-point co-processor".

Comment: I am pretty sure .NET CF 3.5 is targeted generic  hardware and not leverage any process extension. For example my case is ARM11. ARM11 has Vector Floating-Point co-processor and .NET CF 3.5 does not support it. I have heard Microsoft have a targeted .NET CF 3.7 on Zune which supports VFP and a bunch of things but I can't find it. This leave me only one option, code the core in C++ and use C# as front end only. Since C++ can be compiled to support VFP & SIMD so I could expect my math code running at 20X speed of .NET CF floating point emulation.

Comment: Something worth to read (.NET Compact Framework and ARM FPU): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/03/27/net-compact-framework-and-arm-fpu.aspx

Comment: Also this article (Floating point operations in .NET Compact Framework on WinCE+ARM): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/04/06/floating-point-operations-in-net-compact-framework-on-wince-arm.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a good article discussing how to create C++ DLL for C#

http://forums.ni.com/t5/Measurement-Studio-for-VC/How-to-create-dll-in-Visual-Studio-2008-in-Visual-C/td-p/698632

Mentioned by ChinJohn a complete example is located here: http://www.coodtec.com/wordpress/?p=130

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4679858/636019). This deals with declaring your C functions so that C# can P/Invoke them.

A very useful page when P/Invoking is [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net), check it out