# Can I use PInvoke to call method from my own dll?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dll, com, pinvoke

I have some dll writtern by my self. I am wondering if I can use PInvoke to call them from my C# code?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What language is the library written in?

Comment: The library is written using c++

Answer (score 1):

You may use [C# DllImport and Dllexport for DLL Interop](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dllimport) article as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these sources on P/Invoke:

[Calling Win32 DLLs in C# with P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx)

In this answer you might find how you could prepare your dll to make it suitable for P/Invoke:

[Creating a basic C++ .dll for p/invoke in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679858/creating-a-basic-c-dll-for-p-invoke-in-c-sharp)